# how to call a c++ function from elisp

Tags: c++

initially, i'am new to emacs. So I have little expierience with emacs.

In past I used Visual Basic or VBA to work with the Output from some .dll.

Now I'am working a little with emacs/elisp.

My question is, is it possible to use emacs to call a function from a .dll und work with the Output (string Array) within emacs?

If it possible, how can I call the function from the .dll.

In past I searched already to an answer to this topic, but i can't find any exampel to do this.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/04/26/
I don't think it will be easy to pull off.

Comment: See also this: https://phst.github.io/emacs-modules

Answer (score 3):

For reasons that are beyond the scope of this posting, GNU Emacs doesn't have a foreign function interface (FFI), and hence cannot call C or C++ functions out of the box.  (XEmacs used to have an FFI, but that fork has unfortunately died many years ago.)

Recent versions of Emacs (25 and later) support [modules](http://diobla.info/blog-archive/modules-tut.html), a way to call C/C++ code that has been encapsulated in a very specific (and somewhat baroque) manner.  Unfortunately, module support is disabled by default, and hence only useful if you're willing to rebuild Emacs from source.